# printing out the duplicate values in specific columns in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file and I need to print the duplicate values in a column "hash" . so I made this using pandas but I'm not sure what its printing , it seems like its printing an entire row of duplicates which I don't need , I need only duplicate vaults in that column " hash"

the script I made:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("combined_values.csv")
dups = df[df.duplicated("hash")]
print(dups)
```

I also tried this one but it seems to print all the "hash" column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("combined_values.csv")
dups = df["hash"].duplicated
print(dups)
```

Comment: You want a single column with just the duplicated values from hash?

Comment: Yes I only need to print the duplicated values in the column name "hash" , only printing them out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to create a boolean index then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select from the DataFrame where `hash` is duplicated, and just the `hash` column:

```
s = df.loc[df['hash'].duplicated(), 'hash']
```

We can set `keep=False` if all duplicates are wanted:

```
s = df.loc[df['hash'].duplicated(keep=False), 'hash']
```

---

With some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'b': [5, 6, 7, 8],
    'hash': [4, 5, 4, 6]
})

s = df.loc[df['hash'].duplicated(), 'hash']
```

`s`:

```
2    4
Name: hash, dtype: int64
```

Or keeping all duplicates:

```
s = df.loc[df['hash'].duplicated(keep=False), 'hash']
```

`s`:

```
0    4
2    4
Name: hash, dtype: int64
```

Comment: what if the data are in CSV file ?

Comment: I don't understand.`df = pd.read_csv("combined_values.csv")` instead of a generated `df`?

Comment: lol perfect , worked smoothly like smoothie in a hot summer day